# VBA for RFID reader - How to capture Tag_ID in next empty cell in a SPECIFIC Column say starting from A2 till A3000

Tags: excel, vba, rfid

The excel Speadsheet to capture TAG_ID in Column A

[image: 1]

I was trying to capture the Tag_ID ONLY Column A for each tap of the card on the RFID reader.
The time would be automatically output in Column B corresponding to each TAG_ID Capture in Column A.

Here's the Problem:

I must deliberately place the cursor on A2 before allow anyone to tap the card on the reader.
If the cursor is placed elsewhere on the spreadsheet (e.g cursor at H3) then the Tag_ID captured at H3 but not at A2.

I greatly appreciate if anyone can help me to to adjust my VBA code so that no matter where i place the cursor on the spreadsheet,  the TAG_ID to be captured in A2 (in the beginning) then for subsequent card tap, the Tag_ID to be captured in next empty row in column A.

Here's the current VBA code for capturing the TAG_ID:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Now
Beep
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Thank you

I am still a novice in understanding and writing VBA codes.

I have tried other codes like this to test:

```
Sub Store_Reference_Next_Empty_Row()

Dim nextEmptyCell As Range

Set nextEmptyCell= Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

nextEmptyCell.value=Now
```

With this code
the data(error) appeared at the last row of the table instead when i ran the macro.

[image]

If use the card to tap on the RFID reader, I set have to deliberately place the cursor on A2...but no clock in time was output even if the TAG_ID was captured

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is a table on the worksheet created using Insert > Table or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, locating the last data row is slightly different. You don't need to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

*Option 1:*
Assuming the data in column A is continuous (meaning there are no blank cells in between the data) ...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ' Taget is non-blank and on Column A
        If Target.Column = 1 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Now
            Beep
            Dim c As Range
            ' Locate the last row from top
            Set c = Target.Offset(1)
            If c.ListObject Is Nothing Then
                ' the table is full, add a row
                Target.ListObject.ListRows.Add
            End If
            c.Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*Option 2:*
Regardless of whether the data in column A is continuous or not...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ' Taget is non-blank and on Column A
        If Target.Column = 1 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Now
            Beep
            Dim c As Range
            ' Locate the last row of table from bottom
            Set c = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
            If c.Value = "" Then
                ' locate "real" last data row
                Set c = c.End(xlUp)
            Else
                ' the table is full, add a row
                c.ListObject.ListRows.Add
            End If
            c.Offset(1).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

*Update2:*

> Question: At any point in time(If in the beginning have to select A2), if other cell is selected accidentally during the capturing of Data in Column A, it will break the continuity of capturing data in column A.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Dim tValue, c As Range
        tValue = Target.Value
        ' Assumes the length of TAG_ID is 7, modify as needed
        If Len(tValue) = 7 And VBA.IsNumeric(tValue) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ' Scan result is in column A
            If Target.Column = 1 Then
                Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Now
                Set c = Target
            Else
                ' Scan result is NOT in column A
                ' Locate the last row of table from bottom
                Set c = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                If c.Value = "" Then Set c = c.End(xlUp)
                Set c = c.Offset(1)
                ' Clear TAG_ID
                Target.Value = ""
                ' Relocate to column A
                c.Value = tValue
                c.Offset(0, 1) = Now
            End If
            ' Select cell for next scan
            c.Offset(1).Select
            ' Expand table
            If ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
                c.ListObject.ListRows.Add
            End If
            Beep
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Adding the `SelectionChange` event ensures that the active cell is always positioned on the correct cell in column A. This helps prevent new TAG scans from overwriting existing data in the table.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Me.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Set c = Application.Intersect(Me.ListObjects(1).Range, Target)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Set c = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                If c.Value = "" Then Set c = c.End(xlUp)
                Set c = c.Offset(1)
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Update3**

> Question: If I have a range of cells(named it as "NoTouch") not within the table that I do not want the TAG_ID to overwrite but still jump to capture the data in Column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, dataRange As Range
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Me.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Set dataRange = Application.Union(Me.ListObjects(1).Range, Me.Range("NoTouch"))
            Set c = Application.Intersect(dataRange, Target)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Set c = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                If c.Value = "" Then Set c = c.End(xlUp)
                Set c = c.Offset(1)
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the enhanced VBA cater to my Insert>Table for my projects, really appreciate it :). However, there is still a problem.  At any point in time(If in the beginning have to select A2), if other cell is selected accidentally during the capturing of Data in Column A,  it will break the continuity of capturing data in column A.  So still need great help to tackle this problem :).  Thanks

Comment: What's the possible location of `other cell`? In the table? Any cell on sheet? Is it possible to update any cells by users' input?

Comment: Please try the updated code. If it doesn't meet your need, please share the detail about the using scenario.

Comment: Just want output to appear only in column A for any card tapped on the card reader, starting from A2, A3 and downwards along column A. Regardless of any accidental click/select on the other cell.  Eg, If click/select Cell H10 at the start.  Output should be in cell A2 instead of H10. Other scenario is if say output already captured in A2, A3 and A4. Any accidentally click/select say at M2 after the last capture of output say at A4. Then the next tap of card on the reader should be output in A11 instead of in M2.  Hope i have manage to paint the picture of this case as clearly as possible.

Comment: It is doable. But you may need to define the logic for relocating the input. eg. input 813 at C3, I guess it should not be moved to column A. Is there any user input on sheet? It tiggers Change event too.

Comment: This spreadsheet captures TAG_ID for each Card tap on the RFID Reader. If place the cursor to select any cell say H2, the TAG_ID will be output in H2. But I set my table for Column A to capture all TAG_IDs from A2 till A3000. I do not want the TAG_IDs to be output in any other cells. The problem: At the start, cursor has to be placed on A2 deliberately to select the cell A2 to ensure TAG_ID to be captured from A2 till A3000. Possible to set the TAG_ID to be output automatically in Column A , starting from A2 onwards upon each tap of the card on the RFID reader?

Comment: The upated code have fixed this problem. The first TAG_ID input will be in A2 no matter which cell is selected before tag scanning.

Comment: Don't know why doesn't seems to work.  I placed the cursor on other cell and then tap the card...the TAG_ID appeared in the selected cell other than any cell in column A.  Maybe I have  missed out something ?  Really appreciate the great help and definitely you have given me much improved code.

Comment: I have some questions about your testing. Did you use my updated code (the 2nd part of my replay) or your revised version ( pls share it in OP)? Is cell A2 blank before scan? What the result of TAG_ID scan? Is it digit?

Comment: Blur me and you are fantastic! I have just tested your 2nd part of replay. It works at the very beginning to 'force' first reading to be at A2. The problem is - after that,  Say the captured readings are on A2, A3, then A4....what happen if at this point if the cursor is move to place select another cell say at K5. The data output at K5 instead of on A5.  Rephrase my question: Possible to set the TAG_ID to be output automatically in any next EMPTY ROW CELL in COLUMN A , starting from A2, A3, A4... onwards upon each tap of the card on the RFID reader?

Comment: You didn't answer my quesion `Is it possible to update any cells by users' input?`. So the revised code doesn't force all input. It's doable if `TAG scanner` is the ONLY inputting on work sheet.

Comment: `Update2` relocates all scan input to column A.

Comment: It’s awesome, though I am still trying to understand the vba code. Then realised that I still need one more condition to tackle somehow similar issue. What happen if cursor move to select any cell in the table . Possible not to overwrite the data already in the cell upon tapping the rfid reader ? Eg if column A already captured TAG_Id in A2, A3 and A4 .. then if accidentally choose back A2… possible to ignore it and capture the tag_Id in A5? Likewise for the rest of the columns in the table.

Comment: Is it the last condition?

Comment: Yes.  I am really sorry to have troubled you so much.  Very much appreciated for your help in this.

Comment: See the updated code.

Comment: You are really awesome!!! I will try to understand the code as I am still learning. Currently, I am trying to add one more condition. If still not able to crack , I will ask you for advice again. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to disturb. If I have a range of cells(named it as "NoTouch") not within the table that I do not want the TAG_ID to overwrite but still jump to capture the data in Column A.  How to go about doing in.   I was thinking how to add these code in between                        If Intersect(Target, Range("NoTouch")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.Undo.

Comment: Please try `Update3`.

Comment: Awesome code!!! Inserting Me.Range("NoTouch")                                                                                              Set dataRange = Application.Union(Me.ListObjects(1).Range, Me.Range("NoTouch"))  can work only if "NoTouch" is a TABLE right? If it is not a table, there's no way to set it to jump to Column A. Am I right?

Comment: No. `NoTouch` could be either a table (Insert>Table) or a named range ([Create a named range from selected cells in a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-from-selected-cells-in-a-worksheet-fd8905ed-1130-4cca-9bb0-ad02b7e594fd?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461))

Comment: ah! just found out... no wonder some cells didn't work....because of merged cells in within the named range.

Comment: What does `didn't work` mean?

Comment: e.g.  If the range is M2:K10. If M2:N2 is a merged cell.  Click on this merged cell and it  stays there and not jump to next empty row in column A

Comment: When M2 is selected, `Target` is `Range("M2:N2")`, `Target.CountLarge` is `2`. If you have to use merged cell, then you may need to remove `If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then`.

Comment: Coolz! You are Awesome.